# Can I get credit for an event if I don't stick around?

Tags: guild-wars-2

If I contribute toward the completion of a [dynamic event](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Dynamic_event), but either leave the area or log out of the game before it is finished, will I still get credit in the event that another player completes it? Can I receive my karma in absentia?

Comment: I know if you are still within the zone you still get credit. do not know about the cases where you log off or leave the zone. my hunch is that logging out will still net in rewards (because of internet disconnects and the such)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. I have had this happen many times, where I'll be walking along and suddenly get rewarded for an event in a previous zone. I have also logged in to find rewards for an event which I was working on before I logged out.

Comment: I'm not sure you can get rewards if you log out, or leave the zone before the event is completed. I've been playing since launch and it's never happened to me; are you sure about this (it's completely possible that I just haven't noticed)?

Comment: I haven't played in a little while, but I'm almost certain I remember logging in and having rewards for events I logged out in the middle of.

Comment: You can also get "accidental" event awards. If you walk into an area with an event going on and you help hurt a monster that is part of the event, you will get credit (usually bronze level) for the event. I have this happen when I go to an area with a heart quest and the monsters you need to kill overlap an active event.

Comment: @TapenZee, I do this all the time, except not on accident.

Comment: I know I've definitely missed at least one event completion due to leaving the zone - not the area, but the map (i.e. Gendarran Fields, Diessa Plateau, etc)

Comment: Hmmm... I may be misremembering what happens when you leave the zone, but I'm pretty sure about logging out.

Comment: Logout credit might be given if the event is completed soon after you go off (as someone said, maybe to battle disconnects). I wouldn't count on it unless I were sure of the timeframe, and I'm not, and assuming most players think like me, it's best to just stay around (online and in the instance) unless you're ready to forfeit your rewards.